# How to do bulk save / updates without using HQL?

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, hql, bulkupdate

I can use HQL to do bulk operations but these operations do not update the first level cache of NHibernate, so I'm facing various problems because I do not want to clear the session or refresh objects.

Is there any way of performing bulk updates / deletes without using HQL or native SQL with affecting the in-memory state of NHibernate cache?

Comment: NO. As I've already showen you in [this answer to your previous quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26794467/1679310), DML is not effecting in memory state - the session.

Comment: Yeah. Realize that this isa n obvious limitation of using an ORM to start with. If you think an hour about the possible problems you would get you will liekly realize WHY it is like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems that the only way is to handle it manually and refresh the object:

```
session.Refresh(entity);
```