# Avoid N+1 Select with list of NHibernate entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I receive a list of NHibernate entities that were retrieved by code that I cannot modify.  I want to select a property from a child entity for each item in the list, but it is generating a new select for each item.

How can I get the sub-resources without changing the query that generated the entities passed in or changing the mapping (both of which would have an impact on unrelated code).  Ideally, I wouldn't have to create a custom query at this layer of my code either.

Here is a sample.  My entities:

```
public class Property {
    public IList<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}
public class Room {
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}
public class Template {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the function I am calling:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetTemplateNames(Property property) {
    return property.Rooms.Select(room => room.Template.Name).Distinct();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using a **`batch-size`** setting on each collection *(and each class as well)*. Check more here:

#### [NHibernate Criteria with Distinct Parent Load All Children?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26806168/1679310)

In case of xml mapping, add this to your bag

```
<bag name="Rooms" ... batch-size="50">
```

NHibernate will be loading collections for all loaded parent items *(`Property` in the above case)* in batches... So instead of 1 + N, we will get  1 + N / 50